# What does "money will reflect in your credit card shortly" mean?

Tags: credit-card, refund

I was paying for a policy on a monthly basis and decided to cancel that policy. Then I recieved an SMS from my bank saying

> "Pol ref no xxxx has been cancelled on 15/06/2019 and refund of
>   Rs.4956 will  reflect in your credit card shortly."

What does it say? And if I use the amount of Rs. 4956 from my credit card will it be debited from my savings account in the next month?

Comment: How does Rs 4956 compare to the monthly payment? Is is a full payment, or only part of the payment? Is the bank the company that is selling you the policy?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I was paying somewhere near 400 a month for nearly 10 months. It should be paid for 24 months. So I thought that policy was unnecessary for me and I cancelled it. Then I recieved this message.

Comment: [Monetary policy is the process by which the monetary authority of a country, typically the central bank or currency board, controls either the cost of very short-term borrowing or the money supply, often targeting inflation or the interest rate to ensure price stability and general trust in the currency.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monetary_policy) The term doesn't refer to any policy regarding money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They sent you the SMS as a courtesy.

Bank refund transactions don't happen instantly.

"Will reflect **in** your credit card shortly" is bad grammar.  It should read "Will reflect **on** your credit card shortly".  Which means that you'll see the refund *soon* on your credit card.

Comment: Thank you Ron. By the way if the bank has processed my refund can I use the refund amount from my credit card without having to pay for the used amount in the next month?

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan I'm not sure I understand your question.  But... presuming that you've been paying for that policy with your CC, then presumably they are going to refund the money to your CC.  Thus, any balance your CC has will be reduced by Rs.4956.  If your balance had been less than Rs.4956, you'll now have a negative balance.

Comment: Let me try to explain better Ron. I have Rs.20,000 in my credit card which is the maximum amount that I can use for every month. If this refund gets processed, then I'll have Rs. 24,956 as the balance. So if make a purchase for Rs. 4,956 will it get debited from my bank account? (Normally when we have Rs.20,000 in our credit card and if we make a purchase for 5000, we need to pay it to the bank by the starting of next month.)

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan Do you mean 20,000 is the *balance* on the card, or the *limit*?

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan there's a confusion here.  You write "*I have Rs.20,000 in my **credit** card*" and "*I'll have Rs. 24,956 as the balance*", but it seems like you actually have a **DEBIT** card.  Or are you confusing "I have Rs.20,000 in my credit card" with "I have a Rs.20,000 credit **limit**"?

Comment: I am a new user of credit card, so I am confused about these terms. Sorry for that. And yes, 20,000 is my credit card limit for each month

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan with the Rs.4956 credit, you'd be able to make a Rs. 24,956 purchase on your card.  Naturally, you'd then have to give the bank Rs. 24,956... :)

Comment: Should also be "be reflected" rather than "reflect".